# Help with size of text on photos 4272 x 2783

Tags: print-design

When my photo comes off my camera, rebel T3, 4272 x 2783 is the size of photo with a resolution of 72.   I then in photoshop go to change the resolution to 300 in order to have calendars and scripture pictures printed.  The largest size of font in photoshop is 72. 72 is not large enough for the photo.  If I manually input say 150 or 200 for the fontsize, will it print out okay?  I hope I'm making sense.  I'm fairly new to printing my photos for sale.  I also hope that changing the resolution is okay?

Thank you for this site, it looks wonderful.

Kathleen

Comment: Don't confuse font size with the resolution. Font size is relatively arbitrary, and as @CTLYST pointed out, not relevant to font quality either, as they are vectors. Simply size your font to what you want to on your image.

Answer (score 2):

The font sizes provided by Photoshop in the drop down menu are *not* the only available sizes, nor are they any sort of constraint. Those sizes just happen to be some of the more commonly used ones.

You can input any size you want, manually, from **0.01 to 1296 px**.

Since fonts are rendered as vectors, they will not loose quality at even the largest size allowed in Photoshop.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why the largest font size you can do is 72 pt, you should be able to type in a higher number, even if its not in the pull down menu.

But if you are changing the resolutions to 300 dpi, make sure the Resample Images box is not checked when you change the resolution in the Image Size dialog box. This way when you change the resolution the overall dimensions change. The width and height will change, but the amount of pixels remain the same.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will. Fonts are vectors making it okay when scaling and it will not lose quality. This is quite short but I hope it helps.